# Matching something with regex in a string and removing / cutting out everything that did not match

Tags: php, regex, string

I am wondering how to solve this. Let's say I have a string looking like this:

```
xx-123-456-12-xxl-1235-6122
```

I also have an regex that will try match anything that look like this

```
[LETTER][LETTER]-[NUMBER][NUMBER][NUMBER]-[NUMBER][NUMBER][NUMBER]
```

meaning in the strong above it would match this:

```
xx-123-456
```

How do I go about cutting everything else out of that string, that did not match the regular expression. Meaning that everything after `xx-123-456` should be cut our and removed. This would need to work as well no matter where in the string the regex finds the match.

Any ideas / solutions?

Comment: please post the code as well

Comment: I have not written any code? Or do you mean the regular expression? I am using this one: "/((UA|YT|MO))-[0-9]+-[0-9]/" for trying to find a Google Analytics tracking id, which usually looks like this: UA-000000-1

Comment: string.replace( '/(regex)/', $1 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this in php:

1. Use `preg_match` to match what you want and print matched array element
2. Use `preg_replace` and use captured group to use a back-reference in replacement.
3. Use `preg_replace` and use lookbehind assertion
4. Use `preg_replace` and use `\K` (match reset)

Here is one approach using #4:

```
$str = 'xx-123-456-12-xxl-1235-6122';
$str = preg_replace('/^\p{L}{2}-\p{N}{3}-\p{N}{3}\K.*$/u', '', $str);
//=> xx-123-456
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pH6xO5/1)

Comment: That approach gave me: Warning: "preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '^' found"
EDIT: Oops, nevermind. Copied the wrong regex. In your answer the regex seems to be wrong, but in the link you pasted, its correct. :)

Comment: Is it possible to say "x amount of numbers" instead of, for example 3 in the example.

Comment: @KeepSilence The example of anubhava works fine. Maybe you miss something in copy-past!

Comment: @KeepSilence: Do you need this: `^\p{L}{2}-\p{N}+-\p{N}+\K.*$`

Comment: @KeepSilence You can set a min/max value. Take a look at [PCRE pattern syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: Thanks that made it for me. I added a preg_match afterwards to just confirm that the string is good or not, otherwise return nothing! Thanks! Cutted a huge sanitation/validation function down to 3 lines of code... :P

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$txt = 'xx-123-456-12-xxl-1235-6122';
preg_match( '/^[a-z]{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}/i', $txt, $matches );
echo $matches[0];
```

`^` = begin of the string;

`[a-z]` = any characters from a through z;

`{2}` = previous pattern repeat 2;

`\d` = any digit/number

Comment: "This would need to work as well no matter where in the string the regex finds the match" so I think `^` is not necessary.

Comment: @bartoszukm ah ok, my mistake